# I don't know how to fix this bootstrap problem

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mybb

I am working on a MyBB website and I'm having a problem with the bootstrap checkbox formatting. The text runs through the checkbox.

Image of the problem: http://prntscr.com/nfj4vr

When I try to move the text it moves the whole block.

Comment: Please, post some code, otherwise is very hard to help.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! we ask for a [mcve] because we can't reproduce your issue from an image. for example, are you using `for` and `id` to associate the label with it's input checkbox? are you restyling the text using css? are you using up to date mybb?

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: if you can share the code then I can help you more.